# Wierd wine install

Tags: wine

while searching for a version of wine that correctly runs the game I want to play, (AOE 2) I found this:

http://www.darkgamex.ch/wine/

it is a website linked to the download of two custom wine variants that are designed to work with aoe 2. the problem is that I do  not know how to correctly install it.

Answer (score 1):

**Suggestion:** Please make sure to check out [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/), it will download and install the best version of wine known to work with a certain game, manage installed games, etc. It will save you a lot of hassle. You can simply install it by running:

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Lauch it and you're ready to install and play your game. If you *really* want to go on and install this specific version of wine, keep reading.

Those archives contain the source code for wine.

First, extract the archive:

```
tar xaf wineageofempires2-1.3.20.tar.xz
```

Then change into the directory:

```
cd 1.3.20/wine-git
```

Install the `build-essential` package:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Run the configure script to create Makefiles:

```
./configure

# or if you're on 64-bit, use this:
./configure --enable-win64
```

If any errors come up, handle them. You will probably have to install a few extra packages.

When all errors are solved and the Makefiles are generated, run

```
make
```

to compile wine, then run

```
sudo make install
```

to install it.